# XPath: ./descendant[::City or ::Village]?

Tags: xpath

How is it possible to include in a XPath expression the descendants of two types, say, "city" OR "village"s

Knowing that both

```
./descendant[::city or ::village]
```

or this one

```
./descendant::[city | village]
```

does not work?

Comment: `descendant::city | descendant::village`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./descendant::*[self::city or self::village]
```